# Split string by comma only when it's between brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
String str = "[a,b,c,d],[1,2,3,4],[a,gf,d,cvb],[4,3,2,1]";
```

I want to split this string into four parts, like this:

> [a,b,c,d]
>   [1,2,3,4]
>   [a,gf,d,cvb]
>   [4,3,2,1]

I tried this:

```
List<String> splitWords = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\],\\["));
```

When I use this, I get following strings:

> [a,b,c,d
>   1,2,3,4
>   a,gf,d,cvb
>   4,3,2,1]

In this case, I also remove brackets next to commas, but I don't want to do that. What is the regex for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this regex can do what you are looking for:

**"[(.*?)]"**

## Example:

```
String str = "[a,b,c,d],[1,2,3,4],[a,gf,d,cvb],[4,3,2,1]";
Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(str);
while (matchPattern.find()) {
    System.out.println("[" + matchPattern.group(1) + "]");
}
```

that will print:

> [a,b,c,d]
>
> [1,2,3,4]
>
> [a,gf,d,cvb]
>
> [4,3,2,1]

which is what you are looking for...

Comment: i see, let me check and make corrections if any apply

Comment: Yes, that is better. I'm going to mark this as correct. I also did it like this:

`str = str.replaceAll("\\],", "]\n");
List<String> splitWords = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\r?\\n"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    List<String> splitWords = Arrays.asList(str.split("],"));
    for(int i = 0; i < splitWords.size()-1; i++)
        splitWords.set(i, splitWords.get(i) + "]");
```